# getting this error stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`srv112.hostserv.co.za' did not match expected CN=`smtp.office365.com'

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail

I am using sending mail function at laravel:

```
            Mail::send(
          'mail_send_currentopening', ['data' => $input],
          function($message)use($input, $path){
                  $message->to('tech@idigital.net','To noreply');enter code here
                  $message->subject('Current Openings');
                  $message->from('enquiries@mallsystems.co.za','Resume')`enter code here`;
                  $message->attach($path,array(
                    'as' => "resume", // If you want you can chnage original name to custom name      
                    ));
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the information in your SSL certificate, most likely you have smtp.office365.com as the common name (CN) aka full qualified domain name (fqdn) when you should have srv112.hostserv.co.za